# getting module not found after importing packages in swift

Tags: swift, package

I've done a bit of swift, but I've never tried to use a third party package before.   I created a brand new swift app, with Mac/iOS version and tests from the wizard.  I went to xcode, right clicked on the sidebar, and chose add packages, and put in a package by url:

```html
https://github.com/witekbobrowski/EPUBKit.git
```

It goes away for a little bit - and three package dependencies appear on my screen:

[image]

and when I look at my project settings, I can see them there:
[image]

(I actually added the zip package separately after the first one didn't work, just to test it, wondering whether something was wrong with the package)

Anyway - I can now see the packages, browse into them, see code or whatever - and the package found its own dependencies, so everything looks like it's working fine.  But if I go into my swift app main, and add

```swift
import EPUBKit
```

or

```swift
import Zip
```

it just says "No such module ...".
I've obviously missed a step - what am I doing wrong - how do I fix it?  I don't even know how to investigate it, because everything I look at just looks completely fine and I don't get any errors. I tried cleaning builds, restarting Xcode, using the real version of Xcode 13.2.1, using Xcode 13.3 beta - and nothing works.

**NEW LEARNINGS**

so - I tried changing how I'm running it to produce an IOS app - and it's working fine - but when I produce a Mac app, it's like the package isn't even there?   Why would that be, and how do I make it work for Mac as well as IOS?

Comment: in your targets select your project select general, and go down until framework, libraries and embedded content, click un the button + and search the name of the package that you added.

Comment: awesome - thanks - worked perfectly - weird that it only added it to the first target.  Anyway - add that as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of [EPUBKit](https://github.com/witekbobrowski/EPUBKit.git) here, thanks for taking interest in my library!

The issue is reproducible in a new project which kinda makes sense but don't at the same time. I am glad Xcode is not adding a package to every single target in my project but at the same time why does it assume that I want it in the iOS target? Anyway, I know that this question was already answered in the comment and the problem is solved but I might as well just drop more detailed instructions. Maybe it will help someone.

##### 1. Select Project from Project Navigator

Select te target that is not working for you, in this case it's the macOS target. In the **General** tab you will see the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** section. If the package is missing from the list, tap the plus button at the bottom.

[image: Project without a package]

##### 2. Add Missing Library

Look for the one you are missing, in this case its of course EPUBKit and tap the **Add** button.

[image: Choose frameworks and libraries to add]

##### 3. Success

Now the library is successfully added to your target. Go ahead and build the project to run and enjoy your app :)

[image]